# MongoDB: Match multiple array elements

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with next data:

```
db.MyCollection.insert({ 
        id: 1, 
        Location: [ 1, 1 ],
        Properties: [ { Type: 1, Value: "a" }, { Type: 2, Value: "b" }, { Type: 3, Value: "c" } ]
    });

db.MyCollection.insert({ 
        id: 2, 
        Location: [ 1, 2 ],
        Properties: [ { Type: 1, Value: "a" }, { Type: 2, Value: "a" }, { Type: 3, Value: "c" } ]
    });

db.MyCollection.insert({ 
        id: 3, 
        Location: [ 2, 1 ],
        Properties: [ { Type: 1, Value: "a" }, { Type: 3, Value: "b" }, { Type: 3, Value: "a" } ]
    });

db.MyCollection.insert({ 
        id: 4, 
        Location: [ 2, 2 ],
        Properties: [ { Type: 2, Value: "b" }, { Type: 2, Value: "a" }, { Type: 3, Value: "c" } ]
    });

db.MyCollection.ensureIndex({ Location: "2d"});
db.MyCollection.ensureIndex({ "Properties.Type": 1, "Properties.Value": 1});
db.MyCollection.ensureIndex({ Location: "2d", "Properties.Type": 1, "Properties.Value": 1});
```

What I want is to find all items (using any of above indexes) that:

1. match the Location
2. contain properties with (Type=1 and Value="a") and (Type=2 and
   Value="b")

Here is my query (it doesn't work, but looks close to the right one):

```
db.MyCollection.find(
{ 
    Location: { "$within": { "$center": [ [1, 1], 5 ] } },
    Properties: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $and: [
                { Type: 1, Value: "a" },
                { Type: 2, Value: "b" }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

---

Update:

The $all query works better as there is a problem with the $and one (see my comment in the JohnnyHK answer). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a case like this where you want the docs that include a specific set of array elements, you can use the [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/#_S_all) operator:

```js
db.MyCollection.find(
{ 
    Location: { "$within": { "$center": [ [1, 1], 5 ] } },
    Properties: {
        $all: [
            {$elemMatch: { Type: 1, Value: "a" }},
            {$elemMatch: { Type: 2, Value: "b" }}
        ]
    }
})
```

To do it without the `$all` operator you could use:

```js
db.MyCollection.find(
{ 
    Location: { "$within": { "$center": [ [1, 1], 5 ] } },
    $and: [
        { Properties: {
            $elemMatch: { Type: 1, Value: "a" }
        }},
        { Properties: {
            $elemMatch: { Type: 2, Value: "b" }
        }}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Are there alternatives to $all operator (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1748)? There is an open bug for this operator causes it performance penalty and looks like it will not be fixed in next 2 years

Comment: @Kamarey You could also do it with `$and` but I don't know if it would be any faster.  See updated answer.

Comment: that's not right.  You want $all *and* $elemMatch.  See the indexing second for examples: http://www.chemeo.com/doc/technology

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Both of these did work when I tested them.  The `$all` elements behave as if you've specified `$elemMatch` for each one.

Comment: That's because this is a poor test data set to find that bug.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I know what you're getting at, but I did try it with an extra doc where the `Type:2` and `Value:b` parts were split between two elements and that wasn't included in the results.  Let me know if you do find a doc where the `$all` query doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try one where subdocument has one other field in addition to type and value?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I don't know if that case is in scope of the OP's problem or not.  But you're right, if you're not making an exact match then you'd need `$elemMatch`.

Comment: In my real app I do have additional fields within the Property object. I don't catch your above talks. I understand that the query with $and will not work with all cases (depends on data), and there is a problem with $elemMatch in a case there are other properties except Type and Value. Do I right? Can you explain more about it?

Comment: @Kamarey I updated the answer that uses `$all` to include `$elemMatch` so I _think_ they both should work in all cases now.

Comment: Is it true to say that the both queries are identical?

Comment: @Kamarey I believe so, yes.

Comment: And the last question: do you know if there are any limitations for above queries in sharded environment? Specifically the $and query don't use index when I use more than 1 element within the $and array (even without location part). With $all everything is ok

Comment: @Kamarey These queries will work fine in a sharded environment.

Comment: Why does `$all` not work for empty arrays?