# MongoDB: Build query in C# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I stacked to build this Mongodb query in C# driver:

```
{ 
    Location: { "$within": { "$center": [ [1, 1], 5 ] } },
    Properties: {
        $all: [
            { $elemMatch: { Type: 1, Value: "a" } },
            { $elemMatch: { Type: 2, Value: "b" } }
        ]
    }
}
```

Something next:

```
var geoQuery = Query.WithinCircle("Location", x, y, radius);
var propertiesQuery = **?**;
var query = Query.And(geoQuery, propertiesQuery);
```

---

Addition:

The above query taken from my another question:
[MongoDB: Match multiple array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364920/mongodb-match-multiple-array-elements)
You are welcome to take part in its solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how if you want to get that exact query:

```
// create the $elemMatch with Type and Value
// as we're just trying to make an expression here, 
// we'll use $elemMatch as the property name 
var qType1 = Query.EQ("$elemMatch", 
    BsonValue.Create(Query.And(Query.EQ("Type", 1),
                     Query.EQ("Value", "a"))));
// again
var qType2 = Query.EQ("$elemMatch", 
    BsonValue.Create(Query.And(Query.EQ("Type", 2), 
                     Query.EQ("Value", "b"))));
// then, put it all together, with $all connection the two queries 
// for the Properties field
var query = Query.All("Properties", 
    new List<BsonValue> { 
        BsonValue.Create(qType1), 
        BsonValue.Create(qType2)
    });
```

The sneaky part is that while many of the parameters to the various `Query` methods expect `BsonValue`s rather than queries, you can create a `BsonValue` instance from a `Query` instance by doing something like:

```
// very cool/handy that this works
var bv = BsonValue.Create(Query.EQ("Type", 1));
```

The actual query sent matches your original request exactly:

```
query = {
  "Properties": {
    "$all": [ 
        { "$elemMatch": { "Type": 1, "Value": "a" }}, 
        { "$elemMatch": { "Type": 2, "Value": "b" }}
    ]
  }
}
```

(I'd never seen that style of `$all` usage either, but apparently, it sounds like [it's just not documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824341/multiple-elemmatch-expressions-for-matching-array-values-using-all-in-mongodb) yet.)

Answer (score 3):

While I can confirm that the query you posted works on my machine, the [documentation of `$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/) seems to indicate that it *shouldn't accept expressions or queries*, but only values:

```
Syntax: { field: { $all: [ <value> , <value1> ... ] }
```

(The documentation uses `<expression>` if queries are allowed, [compare to `$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/and/)). Accordingly, the C# driver accepts only an array of `BsonValue` instead of `IMongoQuery`.

However, the following query should be equivalent:

```
{
    $and: [
        { "Location": { "$within": { "$center": [ [1, 1], 5 ] } } },
        { "Properties" : { $elemMatch: { "Type": 1, "Value": "a" } } },
        { "Properties" : { $elemMatch: { "Type": 2, "Value": "b" } } }   
    ]
}
```

Which translates to the C# driver as

```
var query = 
Query.And(Query.WithinCircle("Location", centerX, centerY, radius),
Query.ElemMatch("Properties", Query.And(Query.EQ("Type", 1), Query.EQ("Value", "a"))),
Query.ElemMatch("Properties", Query.And(Query.EQ("Type", 2), Query.EQ("Value", "b"))));
```

Comment: The query with $and is not 100% equivalent to the original one. Please see the link at bottom of my question for details. Anyway thanks for your answer.