# MongoDB $elemMatch $in

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

So, I have a database with a load of arrays in documents in it.
I want to find entire documents where my queries are an exact match for one or more array elements using `$in`.

So, document structure:

```
{
  "_id": "76561198045636214",
  "timecreated": 1311148549,
  "unusual": [
    {
      "id": 1960169991,
      "original_id": 698672623,
      "defindex": 313,
      "_particleEffect": 19
    },
    {
      "id": 965349033,
      "original_id": 931933064,
      "defindex": 363,
      "_particleEffect": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a lot of documents like this, I want to find where a document has an array containing both a defindex 313 and a _particleEffect 19 in one array entry which means I'd have to use `$elemMatch`.

I also want to be able to search for many different array combinations at once so for example an array with a defindex of 363 and a _particleEffect of either 19 or 6 which means I have to use `$in`.

However, when I try to put $elemMatch and `$in` in a query, elemMatch will have nothing to do with it since it won't work on an array. I haven't been able to do it.

My attempts so far:

```
{unusual:{$all:[{"defindex":{"$in":[361,378]}},{"_particleEffect":{"$in":[30,0]}}]}}
```

(my latest attempt, simply does not work.)

```
{"$and":[{"unusual.defindex":{"$in":[361,378]}},{"unusual._particleEffect":{"$in":[[30,36]]}}]}
```

and many more where I tried loads of combinations with `$elemmatch` and `$and`.

(finds items in the unusual array but ignores array delimitation IE it will return a document where multiple items will be used to satisfy the condition (so at least one item with a defindex that matches and one item that has the effect.))

I've spend a day and a half on this and have come really far, even finding a question which was almost the same as mine but was missing any mention of an `$in` part. -> [MongoDB: Match multiple array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364920/mongodb-match-multiple-array-elements)

> **tl;dr:** is there a way to effectively do `$in` + `$elemMatch`?

Thanks for reading and being able to read my somewhat badly formatted post, thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use different syntax than the one you're trying that achieves the same result but doesn't run into the limitation in SERVER-3544.

Use this syntax:

```
db.collection.find({ "unusual": {"$elemMatch":{"defindex":363,"_particleEffect":{"$in":[6,19]}  }} })
```

This will match any document which has an array element with both 313 and either 6 or 19.

It also works with `{$in:[]}` for both defindex and _particleEffect, as long as you intend to match any combination of the two lists.

```
db.collection.find({ "unusual": {"$elemMatch":{"defindex":{"$in":[313,363]},"_particleEffect":{"$in":[6,19]}  }} })
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3544

Welp, did a LOT of digging and it looks like that answers my question.
You cannot do $in $elemmatch at this time.

Comment: I don't see how that bug is relevant to your case - you don't have to express yours with $in and $elemMatch you can structure the query in multiple other ways.

Answer (score -1):

Just try this (Tested)

```
{
"unusual":  { 
        $all:[{
            $elemMatch:{"defindex":313},
            $elemMatch:{"_particleEffect":6}
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: This will match one all right but I want to match cases where defindex and particleeffect will each be an $in[]

Comment: You can't have identical keys in an object.

Comment: Like @VictorS is saying. Only the last rule here `$elemMatch:{"_particleEffect":6}` will be applied.

Comment: I think you just slipped up with the brackets: if you change the value for `$all` to `[{$elemMatch:{...}},{$elemMatch:{...}}]` (i.e. change `,` in the middle to `},{`) then both conditions will be tested. Still not a useful answer to the original question though.